# Passing GET URL with Query parameters with Content header 'Applicaiton/Json' type in CURL

Tags: java, web-services, api, curl, jersey

I am trying to get json data from the url `http://localhost:8080/SMI_M3/search_phrase?phrase=Donald`

Using above url in browser I am able to get json data.
But while using CURL from command its not calling the code section of java below and hence not giving same output as in case of browser.

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/search_phrases")
public Response get(@QueryParam("phrase") List<String> phrases) {}
```

I tried following curl command to get json data from above url:

1) `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "http://localhost:8080/SMI_M3/search_phrase?phrase=Donald"`

Its gives following error.`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 24 May 2017 07:19:06 GMT`

2)`curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/SMI_M3/search_phrases' -d phrase=Donald`

It gives no error and no output

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content type and accept are not the same, also you should include them under header option

```
  curl -i --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Accept:application/json"
```

Comment: Its giving error: (6) Could not resolve host: Content-Type while trying this 


curl -i -H --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Accept:application/json" "http://localhost:8080/SMI_M3/search_phras

Comment: @ascii_walker -h and --header are the same, that was a typo, i edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Its working with simple command below:

```
 curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/SMI_M3/search_phrases?phrase=Donald
```